# My fan is very noisy pretty much all of the time - how do I fix it?

Tags: 12.04, overheating, fan

Here is my sensors output:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +54.0°C  (crit = +98.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +55.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +55.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +50.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

I have just Firefox running.

I have a Novatech nfinity ultrabook.

- RAM: 8gb
- Processors: Intel® Core™ i7-3517U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 4
- Graphics: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
- Hard drive: 228ssd
- OS: 32 bit 12.04 LTS

I do not understand why it is running so hot. Also, it occasionally totally freezes and I suspect this is to do with how hot it is. Am I right in thinking that?

Comment: from the output, i think that your hardware do not support fan controlling and also temperature of device is normal.

Comment: What shows up in the `top` output?

Comment: If it's spinning all the time you might wanna check if the bios has a setting for that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not blocking any of the fan outlets.

It generally a good idea to open the case from time to time to clean out all the fluff and dust that builds up.

Fans can become noisy if the blades are dirty.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with notebooks. Because there isn't a lot of space, it's very important to keep the air moving freely through the cooling fins.

Often you can cure this by cleaning the fan and the cooling fins. You'll probably find a lot of dust and fluff in there.

Often there is a shortcut to get to the cooling system, so you don't have to take the whole computer apart.

Also check how much CPU is being used when the fan is running. You can use the command

```
top
```

to see what's going on. Or use the resource monitor from the menu.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be using very much at all. top - 18:17:17 up  1:04,  2 users,  load average: 1.33, 1.68, 1.56
Tasks: 233 total,   2 running, 230 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  7.0%us,  2.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 90.6%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st